# How to write a selector based on ul class element

Tags: jquery

From a div, I need to only select those which are having

`<li class="head headActive">` **present under the ul tag**

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="ordersdiv">
   <div id="addtoordersdiv5">
      <div class="prd-items-detials">
         <ul>
            <li class="head headActive">
            </li>
            <li class="prd-items-qt headActive">
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>


   <div id="addtoordersdiv4">
      <div class="prd-items-detials">
         <ul>
            <li class="head">
            </li>
           <li class="prd-items-qt headActive">
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Right now with the below code, I am getting all div which have `addtoordersdiv` in them

```
var numbers = $('#ordersdiv').children('[id^=addtoordersdiv]').map(function() {
   return this.id.replace('addtoordersdiv', '');
}).get();


alert(numbers);
```

Could anybody please help me?

This is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h34oo4r3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting `div` that have li with both class`head` as well `headActive` in it, you can use:

```
$('#ordersdiv>div:has(li.head.headActive)');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L9vduzkr/)**

Comment: @PreethiJain: have you checked the fiddle.

Comment: This is waht i wanted . this is working fine . thanks once again .

Answer (score 0):

This selector will get any item that is an `<li>` with both classes applied to it:

```
$('ul li.head.headActive')
```